# Jenkins post-build action "Deploy artifacts to Artifactory" doesn't deploy my artifact

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

Using the Jenkins Artifactory plugin I'm trying to push an artifact to artifactory, in a post-build action (a feature of the plugin).

I believe I've set it up correctly but it just doesn't deploy it to artifactory.  There's no evidence in the logs that it is even trying to, and no error.

Looking at the documentation it says very little about this, and it seems it should just work.  I know it can deploy to artifactory because if I do it as part of the release, it does it.  However, it doesn't do it the way I want, so I am doing it as a post-build action.

How can I figure out why it's not deploying?  Any advice would be appreciated.  Are there any good docs on this?

I should also mention that this is a Jenkins maven job.

Comment: my Jenkins jobs have similar behavior with JFROG post-build action. There is no Error or no clue in the logs at least. can you share any? on how you resolved it? 

it was working flawless for years and stopped working after upgrading Jenkins to 2.414.2 and from JDK8 to JDK11.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which artifactory target (jfrog, Sonatype nexus or something else...) you are using But for jfrog , they have a very good documentation and can be found from [jfrog documents](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in) Link .Even the configuration method will be same for any other artifactory target.

If you still not convinced with the documentation, please share the pipeline details you are using or share the Jenkins job configuration screenshot for free style job.

Comment: It is jfrog, and I have read through the relevant documentation.  Post-build actions are mentioned once, and only in passing.

Comment: If you are following [this](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Maven+Builds) and if it’s not working means definitely there are some configuration error. You can open a bug against the plugins.